# Find Good Number between 1 to N

Tags: c

A number is a Good Number when Number itself is Prime Number and individuals digits of that number should be prime.

I don't know what I did wrong in this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int n=257;
    int i,k;
    int count=0;
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            printf("not a good number");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==n){
        for(k=2;i!=0;k+=2){
            if(i%10==k){
                i=i/10;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

I am not getting 3 as output for count.
I tried checking if 257 is prime number and in 2nd part I divided each element to see if every element is prime or not.

Comment: The second loop does not check if each digit is prime. One way to do that, would be with a simple lookup, for example `int ispr[10] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

The part

```
for(k=2;i!=0;k+=2){
    if(i%10==k){
        i=i/10;
        count++;
    }
}
```

will be an infinite loop becaue `i%10` is `7` when `i=257` and `k` won't be that value because it is even number.

It is known that the set of one-digit prime numbers is `{2, 3, 5, 7}`, so you can simply check against the list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int n=257;
    int i,k;
    int count=0;
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            printf("not a good number");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==n){
        for(;i!=0;i=i/10){
            int d=i%10;
            if(d!=2 && d!=3 && d!=5 && d!=7){
                printf("not a good number");
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot the even part

Answer (score 0):

> I tried checking if 257 is prime number.

That part could be fine, even if not well optimized, but I'd suggest to write a function instead, something that could be more easily and consistently tested. The following still uses trial divisions (surely not the most sophisticated primality test), but at least it only runs up to sqrt(n).

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_prime(long number)
{
    if ( number < 2 )
        return false;
    if ( number % 2 == 0 )
        return number == 2;
    for ( long i = 3; i <= number / i; i += 2) {
        if ( number % i == 0 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

> in 2nd part I divided each element to see if every element is prime or not.

Well, this loop has many problems:

```c
for(k=2;i!=0;k+=2){
//           ^^^^   k can only be an even number.
//      ^^^^        The loop stops only when i == 0.
    if(i%10==k){
    //       ^      The last digit (every digit) should be prime, while
    //              here it's compared to an even number. 
        i=i/10;
    //              Here the next digit is considered, but k is not reset
    //              it could work only if the digits were sorted.
        count++;
    }
}
```

---

> I am not getting 3 as output for count.

I assume you expected that value as the number of prime digits in 257, but the title of the question is

> Find Good Number between 1 to N

The approach you are trying to implement is to firstly check if a number is prime and *then* check if all of its digits are also prime. This way you'd have to test the primality of *all* the N numbers.

Consider the other way around: first generate all and only the numbers with 2, 3, 5 and 7 as digits (maybe not the ones with a 2 or 5 as last digit, though) and then test their primality.

This way, given N = 10,000, the following 61 good numbers are [found](https://godbolt.org/z/b4xn6d5sG), on a total of 172 candidates

```
    2    3    5    7   23   37   53   73  223  227
  233  257  277  337  353  373  523  557  577  727
  733  757  773 2237 2273 2333 2357 2377 2557 2753
 2777 3253 3257 3323 3373 3527 3533 3557 3727 3733
 5227 5233 5237 5273 5323 5333 5527 5557 5573 5737
 7237 7253 7333 7523 7537 7573 7577 7723 7727 7753
 7757
```